# Uploading audio using AWS API gateway with authentication header

Tags: java, android, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I am sending audio using AWS API gateway and OkHTTP. Its works perfectly. But when I add authentication header it gives me error

```
Stream Close
```

I am using [Ghedeon's](https://github.com/Ghedeon/AwsInterceptor) library to add signature.

```
String API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME = "execute-api";

RequestBody requestFile = create("audio/wave", inputStream);

AwsInterceptor awsInterceptor = new AwsInterceptor(new AWSCredentialsProvider() {
   @Override
   public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
       return new BasicAWSCredentials(access_key_id, secret_access_key);
   }

   @Override
   public void refresh() {}

}, API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME, region);

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
.addInterceptor(awsInterceptor)
.build();


okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
.url(url)
.post(requestFile)
.build();

Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
String response_body = response.body().string();
```

I have used same code for uploading JSON data. Its working perfectly fine with

> MediaType "application/json"

and gives no error.

How can I modify this code to use it for audio uploading?
Is there any other way to send audio using API gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Firstly, this library is capable of uploading audio files to AWS using API gateways with signature.

It turned out that when we call

> create("audio/wave", inputStream)

This create function closes **inputstream** before it calculates its length. length is required in header **"content-length"**

What I did is I calculat the length of **inputstream** before calling create function and then used it in header.